# Create setup for installing #vb.net app on other PC

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, installation, setup-project

The problem is when I try to install my setup in other PC it gave me errors of database file .mdf

How can I make my setup goes with database auto

T tried a lot of ways to create my setup. Yes I created it but it work just in my PC not in other.

Here is my last connection string:

```
ReadOnly con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
```

> could not open new database 'C:/............./database.mdf' create database is aborted.
>   an attempt attach an auto-named database file 'C:/............./database.mdf ' failed.
> A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened ,or it is located on UNC share.
>   file activation failure, the physical file name 'C:/............./database_log.ldf' may be incorrect.
>   the log cannot be rebuilt when the primary file is read-only.

Comment: Did you deploy the MDF file with your application?

Comment: yeah i did but still not working